# Unable to find/use catkin package

Tags: ros, package, ros-hydro, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I'm new to ROS and are following the tutorial.

I have just created a package as seen in section 4 at the "CreatingPackage" tutorial (did not have enough karma to post the link)

I am now at section 5.1 trying to find my package and look at the dependencies i just set.

$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials

The only response i get is "[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials"

I also tried the command "$ roscd beginner_tutorials" but this returns "roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'".

I can see that the files are present when I look for them in the folder so the problem is that ROS does not recognize them as a package.

I don't know what to do. Please help!

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, ROS Hydro Medusa.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117126/unable-to-find/use-catkin-package/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-12**:
HI, How do you create your package?(where you create the package)
you can use ros build system easier than to use catkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a proper catkin workspace as described in

> catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

Particularly it is to point out that you need to source the created setup.bash each time you open a new shell ( or add it to your ~/.bashrc; make sure to change the path to the correct one for your installation ):

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2014-01-14**:
Thank you, this works :) I was not aware that i needed to source the setup.bash every time...